# "Access violation" error when running C++ program

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, access-violation, runtime-error

I keep getting an error of:

> Unhandled exception at 0x5a6fca58
>   (msvcr100d.dll) in Gofish.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation writing
>   location 0x0ff3b113.

The code that I'm trying to run is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include<Array>
using namespace std;

class Card{
 string suit;
 int rank;
public:
 Card(int a, string b){
  rank=a;
  suit=b;
 }
 Card(){}
 string getSuit(){
  return suit;
 }
 int getRank(){
  return rank;
 }
};

class Deck{
 Card deck [52];
public:
 Deck(){
  for(int i=1; i<=13; i++){
  deck [i]=Card(i, "spades");
  deck [i*2]=Card(i, "hearts");
  deck [i*3]=Card(i, "diamonds");
  deck [i*4]=Card(i, "clubs");
  }
 }
  void list(){
  for(int i=1; i<=52; i++){
   cout << deck [i].getRank() << " of " << deck [i].getSuit() << endl;
   }
  }
};

int main(){
 Deck deck=Deck();
 deck.list();
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}
```

The compiler I'm using is Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express if that might effect anything.

Comment: Clearly it does compile.  If it didn't, you wouldn't have `Gofish.exe`.

Comment: If you are getting an access violation then the code *is* compiling. That is a runtime error.

Comment: this is not a compiler error. compiler error is when you click the nice arrow at the top and it fails to build your exe. here your code is clearly executing itself ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because arrays are zero based.  The highest index in your array is 51 but you are trying to access 52.  Also, in your implementation, the first card, at index 0, will never be accessed.

```
deck [i*4-1]=Card(i, "clubs");
```

Comment: +1. hiting a out of bound array exception on deck[52]. I don't want to add an extra answer since your is good but I would like to add that from programing 101 they teach that a for loop usually is for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfMyArray; i++) so that you actaully go from deck[0] to deck[51].

Answer (score 3):

In the array `deck` of size `52` you are trying to use index `52` which is invalid.

You can change your `for` loop as:

```
  for(int i=0; i<52; i+=4){
    deck [i]   = Card(i, "spades");
    deck [i+1] = Card(i, "hearts");
    deck [i+2] = Card(i, "diamonds");
    deck [i+3] = Card(i, "clubs");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework so I'll give you some hints:

Check your for loop logic.

Remember that the first entry in an array is 0 not 1.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the array index overflow issue. There might be a problem with this:

```
int main(){
 Deck deck=Deck();
 // ... 
}
```

There is no need for that: you could simply write `Deck deck;` instead. But this way, if your compiler is performing no optimizations, you might end up with code that tries to copy a `Deck` object using default assingment operator, which performs a memberwise copy. Thus, will try to copy a `Card` fixed size array, and copying one fixed size array to another will not work properly.